# ioS communicating with GPS tracker

Tags: ios, gps, sms

I am writing an app communicating with a GPS tracker in which there is a SIM card. I figure it's easy to send a text/SMS programmatically from the app to the tracker but what I can't figure out is :

how to have the tracker sending a SMS directly back to the app, so the app can deal with the data.

Could somebody kindly direct me to some tutorials or resources?

Thanks.

Comment: This app is for jailbroken phones, right? Otherwise everything you want to do with SMS is unsupported (including programmatically sending SMS messages).

Comment: Thank you rickerbh. No, the phone is not jailbroken. You normally communicate with GPS trackers via text messages, you send a command and it answers back. I have one and that works well when using the "normal" iphone system. Now it's pretty primitive and annoying to do it that way, so I want to write an app to communicate with the tracker directly from within the app. There must be a legal way doing so, as there some apps in the app store doing exactly that. According to what you say, they couldn't be doing it via text messages then ? Would you know of any other way ?

Comment: Unless the GPS tracker supports some other connectivity such as bluetooth, the only way I can think of doing this would be to use an intermediate server to send/receive the SMS' on the phones behalf. Something like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) might be able to provide the SMS relay for you.